# Reading Multiple Files for Text Mining in R Using TM Package?

Tags: r

I am trying to read few csv files for some text mining assignment.

I have used this command to check the # of files in the working directory:

```
length(dir(path="D:/Shivi/R Project", all.files = TRUE))
```

This results to more than 220 approx.

I just need 3 files from these to use for the text mining purpose however if i use:

```
docs<- Corpus(DirSource(directory = "D:/Shivi/R Project"))
```

this reads all the 220+ files

Please suggest how to achieve this feat.

Comment: `DirSource()` accepts a `pattern` argument that can be used to filter the files. Read `?DirScource`